# DefaultProxy works when I use this on WinForms Application but won't works in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, service, proxy

first of all, sorry for any mistakes. English is not my native language

I've an application that's communicates with an SOAP WS, when I set
`<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">`on the app.config of an WinForm Application, the request response is correct, but if I put this on the same section of an WCF Windows Service I've got the response: **There was no endpoint listening.**

```
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IGDServices" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
      sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
      messageEncoding="Mtom" />
    <binding name="mywsname" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
      sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="mywsendpoint"
      binding="mywsbinding" bindingConfiguration="mywsbinding"
      contract="mywscontract" name="mywsname" />
```

I've tried to set the proxy, but got the response: **Input string was not in a correct format**

```
<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
  <proxy proxyaddress="myproxyadressandport"/>
</defaultProxy>
```

All the parameters or methods of both applications are implemented on the same way.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your English is good. The proxy settings are part of the binding configuration. We usually set up the proxy address in the binding property.

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService"  proxyAddress="myproxyaddress"/>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://10.157.13.70:8300/" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IService">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="VABQIA593VM\Administrator" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Or,

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
            binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
            binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
            binding.ProxyAddress = new Uri("http://abcd");
```

Please refer to the below official document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.proxyaddress?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.0#System_ServiceModel_BasicHttpBinding_ProxyAddress
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/basichttpbinding?redirectedfrom=MSDN
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Hi Abraham, thank you for the answer. I've tried to do this but even with this I'm still getting the proxy message "There was no endpoint listening", also, when I do this on my WinForms Applications it works fine, only in my WCF din't work

Comment: What do you mean that it works in WinForms application, didn’t work in your WCF? What is your WCF project? these two projects should be a kind of Client-side project, which calls the WCF service by adding service reference. In other words, the auto-generated configuration should be the same between the WinForms application and the WCF application.
At last, please pay attention to whether we have applied the binding configuration by using `bindingconfiguration` property on the client endpoint.

Comment: I would like that you share the complete configuration located in the client-side. namely the System.servicemodel section in the Winform and the WCF.